# Authentication Fail Using Outlook Client/Gmail/POP3/VPN

Tags: vpn, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I am posting here based on direction/suggestion found at cloud.google.com.  It is essentially a Gmail access/network/VPN question.

-- I have several Gmail addresses/accounts, all established many (like 15 or 20) years ago.

-- They are all pretty much set-up and configured the same way with same options, in particular I access them via PC using a Microsoft Outlook client and POP3 (fir a reason).

-- I use one of them vastly more than the other three, as it is my primary personal account.

-- I've used Outlook as a local email client for years and years as well.

-- I've used two or three VPNs over time; I started using the VPN I currently have about a year ago, maybe two?; I don't remember if the issue I am now having started immediately at that point or not, but it certainly developed during the last year at least.

So basic problem is the following: when my current VPN is active/connected, and Outlook cycles through the send/receive routine every few minutes per local client setting, all of my accounts process as normal/expected except for my primary, personal account, which fails when Google/Gmail tries to authenticate it.  When I turn off the VPN, everything works as expected.  Also, if I use the following link/URL (https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and login with my primary account (the one that fails), the receive/send with then works for a short period of time, i.e. I have indicated to Google that this connection is trusted and should be allowed...but that "approval" eventually times out after 5 or 10 minutes and I have to refresh that approval page and re-click "OK" if I want the send/retrieve email for that account while my VPN is active

I get that Google might get pissy about my using a VPN (i.e., they hate the thought of anyone valuing their privacy).  What I don't understand, and the primary point of this question, is why does only my primary account fail when VPN is connected, and not the other three Gmail accounts I have set up in exactly the same way?  What makes Google treat this account differently from the others?

Comment: @Paul: thanks...it was hard to figure out just which of the many computer-related S/E sites was most appropriate!  I'll try posting where you have suggested.  :--)

Answer (score 1):

Does this issue occur recently? If so, have you done any operation before that? Such as changing the password?

> fails when Google/Gmail tries to authenticate it

Is there any error reported? If possible, please provide screenshots of relevant problems. (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information)

According to your description, I notice that the issue is related to the primary account, please try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the primary account to check if there are some differences.

In addition, in order to further confirm if the issue is related to the account, it's suggested that you could log in to web mail to check if it can run normally.

Comment: 1) no, not that recently.

2) no, no meaningful error message other than Outlook presenting a dialog asking for user name and password (this dialog is not presented for any other accounts, and also not presented when I disconnect from VPN).

3) "please try to create a new profile": based on symptoms as described, that would be a wild goose chase, I think.

4) "it's suggested that you could log in to webmail to check if it can run normally.": yes, of course...I wish that was the issue, then I would not have needed to post here.


Thanks for suggestions, though :--)

Comment: please flag this question for movement instead copy the same

Comment: Have you tried to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the primary account to check if there are some differences?